# Volley library vs Android SyncAdapter

Tags: android, synchronization, android-volley, android-syncadapter

I've developed an aplication which been using sqlite database. The application needs to comunicate/synchronize (master-master) some database tables after following events:

- On application start up
- On click on refresh button
- In case if uses perform some operation which changes data in the sqlite database

The Android sqlite database do not needs to be synchronized in case if the application is not running. Every sync request needs to be extended of `Authorization header`. The `Volley` lib is already integrated in the aplication.

The question is (considering use case above) whould be better to use `Volley` library for comunication between app and server or implement `AsyncAdapter`? Is possible to combinate both approaches?

Comment: Using a SyncAdapter comes with additional packages like AccountManager, Loaders and Content Providers. Which work in tandem to keep the data up to date with lesser resources.

Answer (score 4):

SyncAdapter should use volley for data fetching like this :

```
public class SyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {

     @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, final SyncResult syncResult) {
  RequestQueue queue = VolleyService.getInstance(this.getContext()).getRequestQueue();
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // we got the response, now our job is to handle it
                try {
                    //Parse JSON response and Insert/Update data to SQLite DB
                } catch (RemoteException | OperationApplicationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //something happened, treat the error.
            }
        });

        queue.add(request);

    }

}
```

SyncAdapter is used for Syncing data on demand or periodically. On your content resolver you can set type of refresh and period :

```
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, "com.android.app", params, 150);
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, "com.android.app", true);
```

Volley service :

```
public class VolleyService {

    private static VolleyService instance;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private VolleyService(Context context) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url,bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    public static VolleyService getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new VolleyService(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }
}
```

Comment: onPerformSync method ends before asynchronous data processing is finished (complicated volley request(s) could take seconds... Could it be a problem? e.g. Could be SynchAdapter thread exited by system as "not used anymore"?

Answer (score 1):

Sync adapters run asynchronously, so you should use them with the expectation that they transfer data regularly and efficiently, but **not instantaneously**. If you need to do real-time data transfer, you should use Volley (or basically an AsyncTask or an IntentService). [Refer Android documentation.](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) So in your case Volley is more preferable over Sync adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Syncadapter is for handling periodic syncs between server and client[SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)

Looking at you app needs, i would suggest volley.